# Creating a After Insert Trigger

Tags: trigger, oracle-11g, plsql

I created a trigger in table tbl_user_order.

and I want to  insert data in retailer_deliver_customer table.
CODE:-

```
create or replace trigger insert_record
after insert on tbl_user_order
for each row
BEGIN
insert into retailer_deliver_customer
(
prod_name,product_quantity,message,delivery_date,delivery_address,pin_code 
)
select
  :new.prod_name,
  :new.prod_quantity,
  :new.meessage,
  :new.delivery_date,
  :new.delivery_address,
  :new.pin_id
 from tbl_user_order where pin_id=:new.pin_id;
commit;
end insert_record;
/
```

I got mutating error once.

If I pass any value in :new.pin_id then it inserted  and if we declare variable for it then get error.

Comment: can we insert data in retailer_deliver_customer(retailer_name,retailer_mno) from retailer_info table( retailer_name,  retailer_MNO ).pin_id common field in both table.using trigger. upper suggestion is correct and this one addtional as new requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the select:

```
create or replace trigger insert_record
  after insert on tbl_user_order
  for each row
BEGIN
  insert into retailer_deliver_customer
    (prod_name,product_quantity,message,delivery_date,delivery_address,pin_code)
  values(
    :new.prod_name,
    :new.prod_quantity,
    :new.meessage,
    :new.delivery_date,
    :new.delivery_address,
    :new.pin_id);

end insert_record;
/
```

You can't `commit` in a trigger. The actions inside a trigger are always part of the transaction that fired the trigger.

Comment: it works for me.

Comment: @surendra: if that solved your problem, accept the answer, so that your question is marked as resolved

Comment: Side note. You can issue `commit` inside trigger body if it's an autonomous trigger (created with  `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;` ).